# Stripping outer brackets from a string

Tags: regex, brackets

I am having some trouble writing a regex expression that will strip outer brackets from a string (I want to ensure any brackets within single/double quotes are preserved):

```
((0)) becomes 0
(0)   becomes 0
('(0845) 187 1262') becomes '(0845) 187 1262'
```

I have got two regexes to match the left and right hand outer brackets:

```
^[\(]*  -- matches out the left outer brackets
[\)]*$  -- matches out the right outer brackets
```

Is it possible to combine both into a single regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not at all difficult, and your regex can be simplified as well, as you don't need character classes:

```
^\(*|\)*$
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!  I never thought of using the pipe (|) character in this context.  I guess I still have a lot of regex stuff to learn.